# making a `data.frame` out of any two same-name variables in two larger data.frames in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, frequency

Using a looping structure in BASE R, I was wondering how I could make a `data.frame` out of any two same-name variables in data.frames `X` and `Y` and then `table` each data.frame?

Without a looping structure, my R code is:

```
X <- data.frame(R = rbinom(20, 1, .4), B = rbinom(20, 3, .3), N = rbinom(20, 5, .7))
Y <- data.frame(R = rbinom(20, 1, .4), B = rbinom(20, 3, .3), N = rbinom(20, 5, .7))

 table(data.frame(X$R, Y$R))

 table(data.frame(X$B, Y$B))

 table(data.frame(X$N, Y$N))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to create the `table` of corresponding columns of 'X' and 'Y'

```
Map(table, X, Y[names(X)])
```

---

If we need to have the levels same

```
Map(function(x, y) table(factor(x, levels = 0:5), 
                factor(y, levels = 0:5)), X, Y[names(X)])
```